# Linking a php module with a .so library on linux

Tags: php, c, linux, php-extension, php-internals

I am working on a PHP module and I am having trouble linking with shared libraries under Linux.

What is the command I need to put in my config.m4 to link against a .so?
If I have my .so file under /usr/lib/ or /usr/lib64/ the compiler should be able to find it right?

my current config.m4 file is shown below

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(my_module, whether to enable my_module support,
[  --enable-my_module           Enable my_module support])

if test "$PHP_MY_MODULE" = "yes"; then
  AC_DEFINE(HAVE_TERR_MY_MODULELIB,1,[ ])

  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(my_module, my_module.c libSomething.so, $ext_shared)

fi
```

Thanks in advance

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this excellent tutorial [Configuring php build system](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4486)

Also you can check out this config.m4 file for reference [Example config.m4 from php-logger](http://code.google.com/p/php-logger-extension/source/browse/trunk/config.m4)

If you still have questions, post them as comments and I will reply :)